# redux-form - Register all fields from state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-form

i am using redux-form v6,

also using react-router,

I need to **register all** my fields, to this big form

**But** i have multiple routes in my app = you can change FORM sections by routing.

When i initialize application, i have **only one** section loaded = i dont have registered **all my fields in redux state** = i **cant validate** required fields in another section, because isnt loaded = redux dont know about them = you can submit and that is bad.

**Is there any way to solve it? register all fields withou initialize all sections?**

Thank you